I am moving to NL soon. My birth certificate has an incorrect name of my mother, will it affect the registration in NL?
I am moving to NL with a work permit soon. I have been informed that I need to do some municipality registration there. I have issue with my birth certificate, my mother name is wrong in my Birth certificate. will this impact the registration upon my arrival at NL ?

What do you mean saying your mother's name "wrong" ? Did her name change? Do you have evidence about the change such as a court order changing her name?

Hi, yes her name was changed but that was never documents anywhere officially in any records. all other documents have different name and my birth certificate alone has a different name. I don't have any record of the name change also. will this impact the NL registration?

I don't know the answer. But it could be an issue.. You can imagine the entry officer or person reviewing your visa application wondering if the differently-named persons presented as your mother are in fact the same person.

Does any other document state your mother's name? It's unfortunate that the incorrect name would be recorded but I cannot think of a way it could impact anything else.

My passport has my actual correct mother name but my birth certificate has a wrong one. will they accept any other document other than Birth certificate?

They will want to see the birth certificate in any case. I don't think errors on birth certificates are rare and if all other details match it shouldn't be the end of the world but I don't really know. Municipal workers in the Netherlands have occasionally been annoying about other documents.
